# Wordpress detect gallery edited when multiple galleries are used

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, plugins, tinymce

I am developing a mce plugin for custom gallery support. I am able to create multiple galleries as usual but the edit/pencil icon (that appears over the gallery in the visual mode) is not distinguishing between multiple galleries. In fact, I am not even sure how to get the gallery that initiated the event. I tried using jQuery('#wpwrap textarea') but it always shows the first gallery.

Here is what I see if I inspect on the edit/pencil icon and I see the same HTML code no matter which gallery I click.

```
<div id="mceu_60" class="mce-toolbar-grp mce-inline-toolbar-grp mce-container mce-panel mce-arrow-down" hidefocus="1" tabindex="-1" role="group" style="left: 489.969px; top: 1027.98px; display: none;">
    <div id="mceu_60-body" class="mce-container-body mce-stack-layout">
        <div id="mceu_61" class="mce-container mce-toolbar mce-stack-layout-item mce-first mce-last" role="toolbar">
            <div id="mceu_61-body" class="mce-container-body mce-flow-layout">
                <div id="mceu_62" class="mce-container mce-flow-layout-item mce-first mce-last mce-btn-group" role="group">
                    <div id="mceu_62-body">
                        <div id="mceu_58" class="mce-widget mce-btn mce-first" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="mceu_58" role="button" aria-label="Edit ">
                            <button role="presentation" type="button" tabindex="-1">
                                <i class="mce-ico mce-i-dashicon dashicons-edit"></i>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div id="mceu_59" class="mce-widget mce-btn mce-last" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="mceu_59" role="button" aria-label="Remove">
                            <button role="presentation" type="button" tabindex="-1">
                                <i class="mce-ico mce-i-dashicon dashicons-no"></i>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The plugin code is at https://github.com/saravr/enhanced-wp-gallery.

Any idea how I can distinguish which "gallery" is being edited ?